# Designing a book entry cell using tabular

Tags: tables

I am trying to squeeze in a lot of book entries (#, title, author) into one page for printing. I am not sure if I am nesting `\tabular` correctly, but here is what I came up with:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.2in]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

% define command for book entry
\newcommand{\bookentry}[3]{
  \begin{tabular}{cp{1.25in}}
    \textcolor{gray}{\textbf{#1}} &
           {\tiny \textsc{#2}} \newline
           {\tiny \textbf{#3}} 
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}

  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|} 
    \hline
    \bookentry{1}{Siddhartha}{Herman Hesse} & 
    \bookentry{2}{Old Man And The Sea}{Ernest Hemingway} \\ \hline
    \bookentry{3}{Catch 22}{Joseph Heller} & 
    \bookentry{4}{The Elements of Style}{Strunk \& White} \\ \hline
  \end{tabular} &

  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    \bookentry{1}{The Latex Companion}{Mittelbach \& Goossens} & 
    \bookentry{2}{The Elements of Typographic Style}{Robert Bringhurst} \\ \hline
    \bookentry{3}{Feynman Lectures On Computation}{Richard P. Feynman \& Anthony Hey} &
    \bookentry{4}{The TeXbook}{Donald Knuth} \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: book entries]

1. How can I change the line spacing between the title and author? I
   think it's using the 10pt spacing, but I am using `\tiny` for the
   text.
2. How can I format the numbers so that they fill the height of the
   cell, and are centered vertically and horizontally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this would be use a `\parbox` instead for the `bookentry`:

```
\newcommand{\bookentry}[3]{%
    \textbf{#1}~\parbox{1.35in}{\tiny\textsc{#2} \\ \textbf{#3}}%
}
```

which yields:

[image]

Another change you should consider is using automatic numbering:

```
\newcounter{BookCount}
\newcommand{\bookentry}[2]{%
    \stepcounter{BookCount}%
    \textbf{\arabic{BookCount}}~\parbox{1.35in}{\tiny\textsc{#1} \\ \textbf{#2}}%
}
```

### Code: Manual Numbering

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.2in]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

% define command for book entry
\newcommand{\bookentry}[3]{%
           \textbf{#1}~\parbox{1.35in}{\tiny\textsc{#2} \\ \textbf{#3}}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}

  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|} 
    \hline
    \bookentry{1}{Siddhartha}{Herman Hesse} & 
    \bookentry{2}{Old Man And The Sea}{Ernest Hemingway} \\ \hline
    \bookentry{3}{Catch 22}{Joseph Heller} & 
    \bookentry{4}{The Elements of Style}{Strunk \& White} \\ \hline
  \end{tabular} &

  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    \bookentry{1}{The Latex Companion}{Mittelbach \& Goossens} & 
    \bookentry{2}{The Elements of Typographic Style}{Robert Bringhurst} \\ \hline
    \bookentry{3}{Feynman Lectures On Computation}{Richard P. Feynman \& Anthony Hey} &
    \bookentry{4}{The TeXbook}{Donald Knuth} \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

### Code: Automatic Numbering

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.2in]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

% define command for book entry
\newcounter{BookCount}
\newcommand{\bookentry}[2]{%
    \stepcounter{BookCount}%
    \textbf{\arabic{BookCount}}~\parbox{1.35in}{\tiny\textsc{#1} \\ \textbf{#2}}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|} 
    \hline
    \bookentry{Siddhartha}{Herman Hesse} & 
    \bookentry{Old Man And The Sea}{Ernest Hemingway} \\ \hline
    \bookentry{Catch 22}{Joseph Heller} & 
    \bookentry{The Elements of Style}{Strunk \& White} \\ \hline
  \end{tabular} &

  \setcounter{BookCount}{0}%
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    \bookentry{The Latex Companion}{Mittelbach \& Goossens} & 
    \bookentry{The Elements of Typographic Style}{Robert Bringhurst} \\ \hline
    \bookentry{Feynman Lectures On Computation}{Richard P. Feynman \& Anthony Hey} &
    \bookentry{The TeXbook}{Donald Knuth} \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I need to use manual numbering, as they are different for the 2 main columns, and come from a ranking. But it's nice to see the code as I can learn from it.

Comment: Ok. But you could use two different counters, one for each column.  Manual numbering is very error prone.

Comment: How about using `\refstepcounter` instead just in case referencing becomes relevant later on?

Comment: @azetina: Since the OP wants to manually number them, I will leave it as such.